# Gruntjs throwing error with requirejs task

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-requirejs

I'm trying to setup a simple gruntjs task using requirejs on Windows 8, but when I run it keeps producing the follow command line error.

[image]

package.json:

```
{
"name": "my-app",
"version": "0.0.1",
"devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "~0.4.1"
}
}
```

Gruntfile.js:
    module.exports = function(grunt) {

```
grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    requirejs: {
        compile: {
            options: {
                appDir: "../",
                dir: "../../build",
                fileExclusionRegExp: /^(r|build)\.js$/,
                mainConfigFile: "js/main.js",
                removeCombined: true
            }
        }
    }

});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-requirejs');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['requirejs']);

};
```

I used `npm install` in the directory, then it installed all the dependencies. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Gruntfile.js is in the `public_html` directory correct?

I think the way you have it configured, you're telling the requirejs task to try to uglify and combine everything in the `skritter-html5/` and it's choking on that, because its running through all javascript files in your project instead of just your RequireJS app code.. What you may want the `appDir` option to point to is something like `"js/myClientSideAppDir"` and then I would output it to `"js/build"`

Try looking over the comments in this file. https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js

They're the best description of r.js options that we've got.

Comment: Whoa, looks like you're right! It was just an issue of me being sloppy about my directories.